# Were 1700's Danish betrothals more likely to be of a couple that went through their confirmation ceremony together?

Tags: 18th-century, marriage-practices, denmark

Was it considerably more common for marriages in 1700's Denmark to be comprised of a bride and groom from the same parish who also had their confirmation ceremonies in the same year or even in the same event or was it more common for some time to separate them by age?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An age difference of at least a few years was definitely much more common. Statistics on this, applying to the second half of the 18th century, are found [here](https://slaegtsbibliotek.dk/910407.pdf).

The numbers show, for instance, that women often married for the first time before the age of 20, while men very rarely did (table 8.7). The age at which 50 percent had been  married at least once was 28 for women and 31 for men (table 8.9).

Comment: Very helpful statistics in that source! One reason for this is that a man had to establish some economic security before starting a family, which usually took some years (with all kinds of exceptions, of course).

Comment: Yes, I believe it is generally accepted that a certain economic independence was required before men could marry, but I don't believe the threshold was set very high.  There is also the fact that the age limit to be allowed to marry was 16 for women and 20 for men. (After a number of changes, that limit was finally set at 18 for both men and women only in 1976.)

Answer (score 2):

Another reason could be that during this period there was the *Stavnsbånd*, where young men were required to ask for the permission of the noble that owned the area to leave their place of birth. https://danmarkshistorien.dk/vis/materiale/stavnsbaand-1733-1800